# Error Message With Missing Text When Trying to Publish an InfoPath 2013 Form to SharePoint

Tags: infopath, error, publishing

I am using InfoPath Designer 2013 to develop a custom form for a library in a SharePoint Online site.  The form is in development, so I published it to a test site.  One day when I tried to republish the form to update it, the form failed to publish, and InfoPath gave me an error message that seemed to have missing text:

[image: Error Message]

I thought that I might have inadvertently changed some setting on my form to cause the error, so I created a very simple form from scratch (just fields for first name and last name) and tried to publish it.  I received the same error, so I spoke with the site administrator, who gave me a different test site to use.  I was able to publish my forms to the second site, so I used it for testing but continued to try publishing on the first site.  After about a week I was suddenly able to publish any form on the first site again (I have no idea why).

For about two weeks I was able to publish without difficulty, then a couple of days ago I began to receive the same error message for any form I attempt to publish on either of the two test sites.  When I run the InfoPath Design Check, it says there are no errors, but I receive the error message for any form I try to publish.  I don't know what to make of the error message, but it looks like the body contains the word "InfoPath" oddly separated onto three lines with the "h" missing.